# Touch event slow to respond

Tags: android, graphics, touch

I need to have an image respond to touch events in Android. In other words the user should be able to move an image on the screen. I'm using the code from the API Demos' TouchExampleActivity project, but what I'm seeing is that the image is slow to respond.

When I drag the image it trails my cursor (on the emulator.) If I move slowly, it trails by a little bit so that there is a separation of a few millimeters from the cursor and the image. If I move faster, the separation becomes worse.

Here are the relevant methods from the Android supplied code sample:

```
public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(context, new GestureCallback());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);                
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mIcon.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Any ideas? Ideally I need the image to follow my cursor (finger) in a "natural" way as if I was moving an object on a table in the physical world.

Comment: on a fast phone like nexus 4, there wont be a lag

Comment: Did you try it with the actual phone? I'm trying on the emulator for Nexus 7.

Comment: Yes, you should try on an actual nexus 7. Not the emulator.